# Windows 10 won't boot into login page after setting driver startup type to demand startup (manual) in process hacker

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers, process-hacker

I am currently running Windows 10 Home ver 2004 64 bit.

I changed the startup type of a driver named EPMVolFlt.sys to demand startup (manual I believe) since Faceit anti cheat software (a game anti cheat software) was complaining about it being incompatible and that I had to restart to unload it (it wouldn't unload on restart and I kept getting that error so I tried to change startup type).

Now my windows doesn't boot up to login page. I just get the booting circle animation and it restarts after that. Then, it boots into repair mode which then fails and results in the blue advanced startup page. I tried enabling boot logs via cmd but I don't see any in my windows folder.

**I can't boot into login page even in safe mode**

Comment: @John The startup repair process failed.

Comment: @John there is a reset option that will remove everything including apps and settings and leave personal files intact. There is also a uninstall recent updates option which I haven't tried. It would let me uninstall recent feature/quality update. I'm not entirely sure if I should try that out.

Comment: @John I am on a data regulated connection and prefer not to lose my apps since I won't be able to re-download them all. Is there any other possible way?

Comment: Blue advanced startup page? Can you get into CMD window there? If so, not all hope is lost (@John, you'd nuke the computer before trying to change the service startup back to automatic, that's a bit harsh and definitely not the only option)

Comment: @hextech Yes I have access to the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to CMD (and admin rights) you can change the startup of services through registry settings. This was my first thought, but the *EPMVolFlt.sys* driver startup probably isn't linked to a service. I don't know exactly what process hacker does to make the driver being loaded on demand. Reverting changes manually would probably include changing registry settings linked to the driver.

There is an easier alternative, though: using Process Hacker command line switches.
`cd` into `ProcessHacker.exe` directory and try using the -nosettings switch:

```
ProcessHacker.exe -nosettings
```

This should revert the settings to default:

```
-nosettings 
Disables settings. Settings are set to their defaults at startup, and no settings are saved.
```

Comment: What does the command do? I ran the command and it opened process hacker. Does it automatically revert any changes to default (meaning I just close the app and proceed) or should I try to change startup type of that driver (I cant find it now for some reason). The driver is located in the drivers folder in system32. Should I manually create a service using the sc utility and then change startup type?

Comment: Creating service and just pointing it to the driver will not help I think. The command should do as described in the answer. Just try closing the app and proceed as you said.

Comment: I did as asked but unfortunately I'm still stuck with the boot loop. I tried creating the service and changed the startup type to system start but it didn't work. The service entry also disappeared the next time I booted up. Any idea why?

Comment: I also enabled boot logs but I don't see them in c:\windows folder. Isn't it ntbtlogs.txt?

Comment: I don't know why your service isn't showing up. You'll have to make a service for drivers, which is not the same as making a "normal" service for .exe or .bat files. But maybe you could try finding the ProcessHacker service and set that to disabled?

Comment: Yeah I made a service for drivers and set an appropriate startup type but it still simply reboots. This time I don't see the service I created previously. Also, the KProcessHacker2 (kernel driver for process hacker I believe) is already disabled (but running when I open process hacker via cmd). It was set to load on startup but I disabled it long time back since it was incompatible with anti cheat software.